# How to Integrate CitiBank Payment Gateway in PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, payment-gateway, apache-modules

We are working on integrating the CitiBank payment gateway integration in our Joomla website, which is deployed in Linux server (CentOS).

Since it is Linux, we are using Apache as a web server.

In that, for checksum value calculate, we got checksum.so from the vendor. We have placed the file in the apache module directory and added the below line in the `httpd.conf`.

```
LoadModule mod_checksum modules/mod_checksum.so
```

And restarted Apache. Then I got the error below:

> Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 151 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `checksum_module' in file /etc/httpd/modules/mod_checksum.so: /etc/httpd/modules/checksum.so: undefined symbol: checksum_module

Answer (score 0):

```
On Line 151 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

You have a module enabled called checksum_module and apache cannot locate the module to enable it so it's failing to start.

You have pasted the file in the wrong location, place it in the apache directory and then enable it like you have.

Linux Console as Super User/Root: `a2enmod 'module name'`

EDIT:

You should have been given the information to utilize the module.

```
/*  
 * configure like so: 
 *  
 * LoadModule checksum_module modules/mod_checksum.so 
 * CheckSumTrans one|two|three
 * CheckSumDir conf/checksums
 * CheckSumPath /checksums
 *
 */
```

Comment: /etc/httpd/modules/ is the default module directory.  I have placed over there. in which location I have to place. Please suggest

Comment: Did the vendor provide you with the configuration files?

Comment: In which directory I have to place.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your information. Where I have to edit the information in the httpd.conf or check.so ?

Comment: The vendor whom provided that file to you should have given you a declaration like I just wrote in my answer in my last EDIT. It will lay out the structure for you of what paths need to be setup.

Comment: They given only checksum.so ( which is not readable form). is it possible to add the above lines some where and run the command a2enmod 'module name'

Comment: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_checksum.so is where I would place it but you still need a conf and load file.

Comment: I am using CENT OS. /etc/http/modules/ is the apache modules. So only I have placed it.

Comment: Yes my apologies for that, but you should have conf files to place in modules-active folder that tells Apache how to work with that .so file.

Comment: I mean need a additional conf file from vendor ?

Comment: Thanks for your continuous support giving for to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes and they should tell you how to further implement this, just dropping a file in the directory isn't enough, there are other factors that need to be checked as well.

Comment: Ok. generally if we want to add .so file, is placing the file in module directory and add the LoadModule in the httpd.conf is enough ?

Comment: Yes that is the usual scenario, in your case there could be dependencies missing, even with PHP depending on what they have coded in that .so file so it's something they should provide to you for using that file.

Comment: To my knowledge no it may not be solved with just the checksum.so file.